# share NSString via airdrop for my application only

Tags: string, ios7, sendmessage, airdrop, uiactivitytypeairdrop

I want to send one string via airdrop feature, but this sharing happen only in my application. Currently when I am sending one string via airdrop, the other device can receive this string even if my application is not installed.

Can you please let me know how to restrict this airdrop feature for application specific only?

Comment: You should not use Airdrop for this. You should use the Multipeer Connectivity framework. (It's almost as easy to use.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [restrict airdrop feature for specific app only ios7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20799123/restrict-airdrop-feature-for-specific-app-only-ios7)

Comment: Sure you can use AirDrop for this. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20799123/restrict-airdrop-feature-for-specific-app-only-ios7/20844881#20844881